# How to get width/height of a movie clip in CreateJs?

Tags: createjs, flash-cc

In AS3.0 it is like:
      mc.width and mc.height

In AS2.0 it is like:
      mc._width and mc._height

What about createJs
      mc.????

Comment: The answer is get "nominalBounds" and then get width and height:

var bounds = mc.nominalBounds;
bounds.width will give you width and 
bounds.height will give you height

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the MC was generated by Flash then you can use either `myMC.nominalBounds`, which returns the first frame's bounds, or `myMC.getBounds()` which returns the current frame bounds. These values will represent the author-time dimensions, and will not reflect changes you made to the contents of the MC in code.

If the MC was not generated by Flash, then you can still call `getBounds()`, but it will not include bounds for Shape instances (unless you have set bounds on them with `setBounds()`).